# Regenerate BIG threshold scaled images

Tags: images

I'm building a photo portfolio website so I need the images to appear at their highest quality even in a few years when we all have larger higher-res monitors.  So I am uploading the full-res version of photos.  I turned off the "-scaled" image threshold of 2048 while setting up the site.  I figured out how to set it at 3000.  Now I want to re-generate all those scaled images at 3000px.

I've tried the Regenerate Thumbnail plugin, and the ImageMagik Engine plugin, both rescale all the smaller sizes but don't create a new scaled image at 3000.  The Regenerate Thumbnail plugin appears to be making a "-scaled" file but it is still full-res.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Have you also either changed the size limit on the 'large' image size, or added a Custom size thats set to 3000px? It might help to create yourself a custom image size in this case, not least because you could increase it (and regenerate) in future? Useful article: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-image-sizes/

Comment: Thanks @t2pe, in 5.3 wordpress added a new image called -scaled.jpg that is created every time you upload an image above a certain pixel threshold.  It is designed so you can upload a full-res image but wordpress will only ever serve an image that is ~2000px.  But this whole process isn't in the normal image resizing function of wordpress core so it is hard to trigger again.